# Elementor Form - WP

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, elementor, wpforms

I have a regular Elementor form on my website, and in one cell, the text has a link. Does someone have a CSS hover selector method for changing the text's colour when you move the cursor on that particular text?

I do not know if I can use this part

Comment: please add inforamation what did you try and add [mre] and read [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.